# MVC3 LDAP Lookup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ldap, lookup

I have an MVC3 project with a requirement to use LDAP to fill in several personnel properties on one of my Model classes.  I have done this before in .Net 3.5 but wasn't sure how to approach it in MVC3.  Would I take the same approach or is there an HTML helper or some other mechanism in MVC3 that I could/should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep doing what you have been doing.  When building your ViewModel (preferably in a repository layer), you can use LDAP as your data source for the necessary properties.

You do not want to do this in a view, as the view should not have any logic other than presentation logic.

Comment: Agreed, any lookup of any kind should be done in your model/data layer.

Comment: @Counsellorben...thanks.  I think what I need is a modal dialogue box (similar to Outlook) that loads a list of LDAP users to be selected from.  Does this correlate with your comments?

Comment: Absolutely.  You can create a PartialView which loads into your modal box.  Use an AJAX call to your controller, which then calls to your repository to get the user list model, and the controller will pass your user list model back to the partial.  You can also use an autocomplete as well.

Comment: Fantastic comments.  Thanks!  Do you have any links or examples of autocomplete and/or modal boxes.  I am super new to MVC3

Comment: Here is a good link to start with for modal dialogs:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQuery-Modal-Dialogs.aspx.  This is pre-MVC3, but gives some good basic info and examples.